# VIF function returning error message

Tags: r, variance-inflation-factor

I'm trying to perform a VIF on a multivariate regression model, but when I ran the `vif` function in r I get an error.

Code and error below:

```
vif(analys3.lm)
Error in if (names(coefficients(mod)[1]) == "(Intercept)") { : 
  argument is of length zero
```

The intercept is still there in my model though.

```
analys3.lm<- lm(formula = cbind(df$col1,  
                                df$col2) ~  
                  df$col3+ df$col4,
data = df)
```

Comment: What's `analys3.lm`? Can you show us how to create it, or something like it, that has the same problem?

Comment: @Spacedman I edited my question and added the information on `analys3.lm`

Comment: I'm guessing that `VIF` can't deal with an `mlm` object (multiple DVs). Run separate models and check them. Also, you should omit `df$` from the formula.

Comment: @Roland thanks, that worked perfectly. If you put it as an answer I can select it.

Comment: You should explain where your `vif` function comes from, there's several packages with a `vif` function (car, rms,...) and MASS isn't one of them, so I don't know why you've tagged it with "mass".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, `vif` can't deal with an `mlm` object (multiple DVs). Run separate models and check them.

Comment: The help page for `car::vif` says: "VIFs or GVIFs for linear and similar regression models without intercepts are generally not sensible."